# How can I sort 2D Line-of-Sight vertices to form a correct Line-of-Sight Polygon?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Trying to sort an array of vertices where you have either 1 or 2 points on an angle. Now, I need to sort all the angle-points of angles with 2 points so that the point before doesn't connect to the wrong point of the angle and therefore doesn't form some kind of intersection with objects but a correct representation of a Line of Sight.[Vertices unconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avqrh.png)

Currently, I retrieve all the vertices and sort them based on their angle relative to the source point (currently set as (0, 0)).

```
private ArrayList<Vector2D> sortLightVertices(ArrayList<Ray> lightRays) 
{
    sortRaysByAngle(lightRays);
    Vector2D lightSourcePosition = new Vector2D(0,0);
    ArrayList<Vector2D> lightRayPoints = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Ray ray : lightRays) {
        Vector2D[] rayPoints = ray.calculateRayPoints(); // rayPoints[0] closest point, rayPoints[1] farthest point

        // Check if there are valid ray points
        if (rayPoints != null) {
            if (rayPoints.length == 2) {
                // 2 points detected
            } else {
                // 1 point detected
            }
        }
    }
    
    return lightRayPoints;
}
```

Now, I need a logic to correctly prioritize adding either point 1 or 2 of an angle first or second, but I'm unsure of the exact approach.

Comment: You want to sort the 2 points by their distance to the source? Use distance formula?

Comment: Not exacly, @trincot. If I were to sort the array this way, I would get a polygon like this: [Add each angle-points with the nearest point first and the farthest point last](https://imgur.com/a/tPewB3v). So they would connect correctly in some cases but incorrectly in others, where it would need to be a reversed positioning in the arraylist. To detect which order they need to have is basically the issue i am having.

Comment: Hmmm... then I don't understand what you need. I think it could help if you would provide the code that initialises a simple example setup, calls this function, and prints the output. Then explain what the expected output is and how it differs from what you get.